# why online tools can not find my MX record?

Tags: domain-name-system

i have these dns records on my server

```
 xxx.com         MX      10  mail.xxx.com.
 mail.xxx.com    A           192.168.xx.xx
```

i can send and receve email but when i test my dns with online tools i get this error for example

```
I did not detect any MX records so you probably don't have any 
 and if you know you should have then they may be missing at your nameservers!
```

why? 
my registrar should something for example register or set some setting?

Comment: Please consider very seriously not redacting your domain name.  These problems are usually much easier to solve when you're open with us.

Comment: Are you saying that your domain name is `xxx.com`?  This seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Thanks, that's better.  Online tools cannot find an `MX` record because you're not publishing one through your declared nameservers; `dig mx helinus.com @dns1.name-services.com` returns no answer.

Comment: It means you don't have an MX record.  I accept that you think you do, but you don't.  You should probably set one.  And, arguably, get someone who has some clue to run your DNS setup.

Comment: When you say "on my server", what *precisely* do you mean?

Comment: Does your DNS provider have some kind of magical wildcard record setup?  Perhaps that is causing problems.  Signs point to yes, since `dig randomgarbletygobbledygook.helinus.com.` actually returns a result.  Anyway, what happens is you disable the wildcard record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

192.168.56.78 is not a valid IP address for Internet ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network ). You must specify a valid IP and have NAT/firewall publication.

Comment: sorry that ip is just for test

Comment: you need check your smtp daemon logs for troubles. run "netstat -anl " and check if ports 25 ( smtp ), 110 ( pop3) , 143 ( imap ), 993 ( imaps ) and 995 ( pop3s ) are listening. check your firewall settings.

Comment: you mean this may be because of firewall or something like this?

Comment: i checked your dns. it´s no firewall. correct MX record is "@ IN MX 10 server.domain.com."

Comment: Whois is your DNS provider ? http://www.enom.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using dig on Linux or nslookup on Windows.  Set the type to MX.  Sometimes, web interfaces of hosts (hosting companies, hosting providers) will automatically append your domain for you - and it won't be obvious when you look at it through their interface.

I can't be certain in the "example.com" case you provided above.

It's possible your MX record may be showing "example.com.example.com".